# How to make my Action working?

Tags: c#

I have code below: I get error like "Operator '.' cannot be applied to operand of type 'void'". Is there anybody can explan the reason and modify the code please?

```
void Main()
{
    Claims.AsEnumerable().Select((claim, no) => Populate(claim, no)).ToList().ForEach(Modify).Dump();;
}

public Func<Claim, int, string> Populate = (claim, no) =>
{
    return "#" + no.ToString() + " " + claim.Applicant.FirstName + " " + claim.Applicant.LastName;
};


public Action<string> Modify = p =>
{
    p = p + "!!!";
};
```

Comment: Your mistake is using `ForEach` instead of `Select`. Figure out why :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
....ForEach(Modify).Dump
```

`ForEach` returns `void`. You *could* rewrite it as:

```
var list = Claims.AsEnumerable()
                 .Select((claim, no) => Populate(claim, no))
                 .ToList();
list.ForEach(Modify);
list.Dump();
```

However, then you'll see that you aren't actually modifying the list at all - the code in `Modify()` changes the *parameter* value, but that won't change what's in the list. Each value in the list (each string reference) is passed to the action in turn. The value is copied into the parameter, and you then change the parameter value... but that isn't connected to the list. This isn't really LINQ-related - it's simple C#. For example:

```
string x = "hello";
Modify(x);
Console.WriteLine(x); // hello
```

See [my article on parameter passing](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html) for more details.

In general, LINQ encourages you *not* to try to make in-place modifications though. It would be cleaner to change `Modify` to a `Func<string, string>` and use `Select` - no list required:

```
Claims.AsEnumerable()
      .Select((claim, no) => Populate(claim, no))
      .Select(Modify)
      .Dump();
...
public Func<string, string> Modify = p =>
{
    p = p + "!!!";
    return p;
};
```

Or more simply for `Modify`:

```
public Func<string, string> Modify = p => p + "!!!";
```

(As an aside, I'd also strongly discourage you from using public fields, but that's somewhat by-the-by here.)

Comment: Come on! This wont work... Edit: Downvote wasn't me!

Comment: @leppie: It will compile, which is the first problem. *Then* the OP can see that it's not going to modify the list (as I've now explained at the end)

Comment: The reason for it not mutating might not be obvious to the OP :)

Comment: @Jon, it pass compile. but the result is not expected. It seems the Action not be run. There is no "!!!" append to the end for each line.

Comment: @Matthew: No, the action is being run - you'll be able to see that if you add logging in there or use a debugger - but you've misunderstood how parameters are handled in C# (or what ForEach does).

Comment: ... and mutability :-) (love the first edit reason!)

Comment: @ thanks Jon, but the latest version can not pass compile."The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Select<TSource,TResult>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,TResult>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly."

Comment: The mission in stack overflow should not be giving you compilable output, but explaining what the problem is (which @JonSkeet has), you should figure out your own code once you understand the problem with the original one

Comment: @Matthew: Did you change the type of `Modify` as I suggested? I suspect not. (Put it this way - it compiles for me.) It's possible that you're using a different version of C# of course...

Comment: @JonSkeet why do you discourage the use of public fields? Any link? (I have asked myself this question several times). I tend to use properties just out of "fashion", but I've never found the downside of using fields in many cases.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I actually have a PDF copy of your book handy on my desktop, but have never taken the time to read it from start to finish (I use it as a reference when I'm in doubt, but this time, it seems I didn't :-) )

Comment: @JonSkeet, If the parameter passed into the Modify is a Class object with store data in class Properties, the Modify will change the Class value as expect. Is it correct?

Comment: @Matthew: Yes. You need to distinguish between changing the value of the parameter, and making changes within the object that the value of the parameter refers to.

Answer (score 0):

I know below answer may not the best solution. but it pass compiled and give me expect result like below:

## 0 Deborah Russell!!!

I would thanks all the guys who was help me especially Mr. "Jon Skeet". He goes deep explain. Thanks a lot.

```
void Main()
{
    Claims.AsEnumerable().Select((claim, no) => Populate(claim, no)).ToList().ForEach(Modify);
}

public Func<Claim, int, string> Populate = (claim, no) =>
{
    return "#" + no.ToString() + " " + claim.Applicant.FirstName + " " + claim.Applicant.LastName;
};

public Action<string> Modify = p =>
{
    (p = p + "!!!").Dump();
};
```

Comment: Well, the important thing is that you understand why your current code behaves the way it does, and why the previous code didn't compile (and then compiled but didn't do what you wanted).